# Flask App not Working After Build Succeed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, web-deployment

Flask App works fine locally and even succeeded Build.
I just can't understand this error.
`Logs`:

```
2021-07-18T10:28:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-07-18T10:28:42.023914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=24g1h015-2591-4c3e-9887-c6767d50ec51 fwd="116.88.77.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-18T10:28:42.464216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=50f62645-ac6e-487a-2491-985f9ad6b329 fwd="116.88.77.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: How you are running your app locally. `app.run()` or directly. If  you are using app.run() then in which file it is. Please edit your question include required information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the heroku client and type:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

to enable the web dynos.
Or instead declare a procfile in your root directory:

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi
```

See more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python?singlepage=true#define-a-procfile)